# Does jquery ui button call affect the DOM hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to expand/hide a piece of content. I then changed it such that the link used to expand/hide the content is a button and that broke it. Here is the code working before I changed to a button:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
<a class="toggle" href="">Expand box 1</a>
<div class="contentHidden" style="display:none;">Hidden 1</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<a class="toggle" href="">Expand box 2</a>
<div class="contentHidden" style="display:none;">Hidden 2</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {

    $(".toggle").click(function(event) {
        $(event.target).parent(".content").find(".contentHidden").toggle('slow');
        event.preventDefault()

    });

});
</script>
```

However if I change the function to the following it no longer works:

```
$(function() {

    $(".toggle").button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e'} });
    $(".toggle").click(function(event) {
        $(event.target).parent(".content").find(".contentHidden").toggle('slow');
        event.preventDefault()

    });


});
```

Its as if the call to button() changes the hierarchy and my search no longer returns the '.contentHidden' div

Regards
Des

Comment: +1 for providing code and HTML, but please consider using JSFiddle next time to provide a practical example to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JQuery UI `button()` creates a new hierarchy below the original link (adds a couple of spans). One of these spans is the new clickable item, so it goes wrong for this reason alone (the clicked element is one level deeper than before), so use `closest` instead of `parent`:

```
$(".toggle").button({
    icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e'
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '.toggle', function (event) {
    $(event.target).closest(".content").find(".contentHidden").toggle('slow');
    event.preventDefault()

});
```

### Working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HxKLy/

The other issue, of using click instead of say a deferred `on` is actually a red herring in this instance, but I will retain below for reference.

Binding to specific DOM elements with click, means that as soon as you change the DOM that click event has been detached. Generally you will want to use the deferred calling syntax of `on` instead of a `click`, but in this case it makes no odds.

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle', function(event)...
```

instead of

```
$(".toggle").click(function(event)
```

Just to prove it was not the actual issue, here is a variation of the fiddle with the click back:

### http://jsfiddle.net/HxKLy/1/